# Auntoincrementable en el HTML

Tags: html, python, django

Tengo el siguiente código html y lo que necesito es que `tb_header1` vaya incrementando los valores de `i`,`j` en 1 , y `rangos` vaya incrementando en 1 el valor de `a` (en cada `for`).

```
{% for atributo in tb_header %}

 <td class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTables-example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label={{ atributo }}": activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 254px;">{{ atributo }}</td>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Nro </td>
    <td>Label</td>
    <td>Count</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>                                                    
    <td>{{tb_header1.i.j}}</td>
    <td>{{rangos.a}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: en django, tenes idea como hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías emplear un [Filtro](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-filter-reference) , para realizar la operación de [Suma(add)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#add) **(+1)** a cualquier variable dentro de los templates.

**Ejemplo** *(En tu View)*

```
def index(request):
    lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'lista':lista})
```

*(En tu Template)*

```
{% for atributo in lista %}
   {{ atributo |add:1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Salida**

```
2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: y donde inicializo i , j ?

Comment: `i` , `j` para qué necesitas declarar e inicializar dichas variables ?

Answer (score 1):

no se si conoces el objecto **foorloop** en los Django templates. Es un objeto que se crea automaticamente en el scope de un bucle for y sus principales propiedades son:

- **foorloop.counter**: Comienza en 1 y se incrementa en cada iteración.
- **foorloop.counter0**: Comienza en 0 y se incremente en cada iteración.

Tiene más propiedades que puedes revisar en:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#for

```
{% for item in list %}
    {# Esto imprimira las veces que ha iterado el bucle for, comenzando con el valor 1  #}
    {{ foorloop.counter }}
{% endfor %}
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Suerte y Saludos!

Comment: Yo te recomendaria que añadas un ejemplo, si es posible, ya que las respuestas con enlaces externos son propensas a que no funcionen si el enlace se elimina en algun momento

Comment: Pensé en incluir un ejemplo de código, mas no entendí bien la necesidad que tenía de incrementar las variables en una unidad en cada iteración. Y el enlace que incluí aunque tienes razón de que puede dejar de estar disponible, es la documentación oficial de Django así que tiende a estar disponible, y lo importante que pienso le puede ser de utilidad esta en lo que explique. Tal vez sea bueno incluir un ejemplo de como se utiliza que en la documentación no lo muestra.